# Which X-Y chromosomes have the developmental genes for mammals?

Tags: genetics, embryology, evo-devo

I know that for a given mammal, half the chromosomes come from father and half from mother. This is typically denoted as x-y. I've recently read about "toolkit" genes that control how a cell develops into an embryo into an organism. **I'm interested which set of chromosomes(x,y or both) contains these toolkit genes for development of an organism from a fertilized cell?**

In other words, does an X chromosome know how to build a female and Y chromosome how to build a male, or is it some "overriding" of developmental instructions that Takes place when Y is present?

Comment: Can you clarify what "toolkit" genes you are referring to? Do you have a link/citation for the source you read about them from? I'm guessing you are not referring to the [toolkit genes listed here](http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/variation/toolkit/), so a bit more clarity might be helpful.

Comment: That sounds like the toolkit genes I'm referring to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, while half the chromosomes come from each of the two parents, these two sets of chromosomes are *not* termed X and Y (they would usually be called maternal and paternal).  The terms X and Y refer to potential members of just one pair of the 23 pairs (in humans) of chromosomes, and X chromosomes can come from either the mother or the father.  The presence or absence of a Y chromosome determines sex in mammals.

The Y chromosome contains one gene, SRY, which determines sex, and almost no nother genes.  SRY simply switches on the "make a male" program in the cells.

Essentially all other genes, including any toolbox genes, come from both parents, one copy from each.  (An exception, in males, are those genes on the X chromosome, which in males are present in only one copy and which came from the mother.  Another exception is mitochondrial genes.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @mgkrebbs response, I'd add that many genes are controlled by epigenetic mechanisms [which may mask one of the parental copies by methylation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genomic_imprinting#Imprinted_genes_in_mammals).  This can be a specific effect where, [the active gene is specifically from either the father or the mother](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2975825/). Mosaicism, where one copy of gene is randomly inactivated in any given cell, is also possible.  The classic example of this is [X chromosome mosaicism](http://www.vivo.colostate.edu/hbooks/genetics/medgen/chromo/mosaics.html), where the entire X chromosome in each cell of a female is silenced. (At least in the case of humans and animals like humans)

Comment: There's also this really cool example of a gene for a voltage-gated potassium channel, in which the paternal copy is methylated by a paternally-expressed ncRNA from the same locus (that site is methylated maternally).  If this is disrupted, it results in developmental defects. <Shameless plug for [an unanswered question of mine](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7691) that has the relevant links.>

Comment: There are surveys of such genes from mouse studies, my favorite is MEST. I took a shot at that one @dd3 :)